# Custom dialog layout widget drawing issue

Tags: android, dialog

I am trying to create a custom dialog configured with a couple of textviews, an edittext, scrollview and a "Ok" button. For some reasons, I have not been able to correctly align the "Ok" button in the dialog.

My snipped code for the creation of dialog is as below:

```
      mLineupDialog=new Dialog(context,R.style.CustomDialogTheme);

           mLineupDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN); 
           View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null, false);
           rg = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
           RadioGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
                           RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                           RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

           for (int i = 0; i < lobjs.length; i++){
                   rb = new RadioButton(context);
                   rb.setText(lobjs[i].carrierName);               
                   rb.setId(i);
    //             rb.setTextColor
                   rg.addView(rb, layoutParams);
               }                  

           zipEntry.setText(mZipCode);  
           mPrefs.edit().putString(sharedZipEntry, mZipCode).commit();
     }             

       mLineupDialog.setContentView(view);            

       Button Ok =(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.lineupdialogButton);
```

My Layout file is as below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linlayoutBase"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/favorite_dialog_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/add_remove_to_favs_question_bottom_bubble"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lineup_heading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/favorite_dialog_text_margin_left"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/favorite_dialog_text_margin_top"
        android:text="@string/sel_lineup"
        android:textColor="@color/white_font"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fav_alert_text_size"
        android:typeface="sans" >
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/zipcode_prompt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/favorite_dialog_text_margin_left"
            android:text="@string/sel_zipcode"
            android:textColor="@color/white_font"
            android:textSize="@dimen/fav_alert_text_size"
            android:typeface="sans" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/zipEntry"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white_font"
            android:textSize="@dimen/fav_alert_text_size"
            android:typeface="sans" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearMain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/favorite_dialog_text_margin_left" >

            <RadioGroup
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/favorite_dialog_text_margin_left"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/white_font"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fav_alert_text_size"
                android:typeface="sans" >
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lineupdialogButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/favorite_dialog_button_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/favorite_dialog_button_ok_text"
        android:textColor="@xml/info_panel_button_text_watch_selector"
        android:textSize="@dimen/favorite_dialog_button_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" >

        <!-- android:layout_weight="1" -->

    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is the OK button is just getting laid out partially out of the bottom border of dialog box. . Any suggestion to fix this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!!

[Image of the custom dialog attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWbx9.png)